# Why is SQL Server UPDATE query only copying the first row from the source instead of copying all rows from the source?

Tags: sql-server

So I'm trying to copy a whole column from one table to another.

```
UPDATE target SET col1 = source.col1 FROM source
```

And while the query seems to be working, it only copies the value of the first row from the source column into all the rows of the target instead of copying all values from the source to as much rows as possible into the target.

Note: The source column has less rows then the target, but I tried to use (example amount of rows) `TOP (100)` to match the amount of the source table while the query was working it was still the same result.
And I also tried with the where clause to match the target rows and again it seemed to be working but with the same result as before. (Example) `WHERE target.col1 LIKE 'ABC%%'

Am I missing something here?
Is it supposed to work like this?
Help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Tables are inherently unordered. You need to tell (us, and) SQL Server how to match up rows in `target` with rows in `source`. Add some *sample data* and *expected results*.

Comment: `it only copies the value of the first row from the source column into all the rows of the target` that's exactly what you told the database to do. Update *all* target rows with some unspecified value from the source. Since there's no specific order, the server is free to use the row that's easiest to retrieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is missing here is a primary-foreign (or maybe even primary-primary) key relationship which *relates* one table to the other.  Your update query should really look something like this:

```sql
UPDATE t
SET col1 = s.col1
FROM target t
INNER JOIN source s
    ON t.pk = s.fk;
```